# SQL subselect group function not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm facing a problem with an SQL subquery: I need to write a query which returns the courses where the number of subscriptions (count(employeeNumber)) is greater than the maximum allowed number of subscriptions (Maximum).

In my original query I'm getting following error:
**Group function is not allowed here**.

The query:

```
SELECT c.CourseName 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON s.courseCode = c.CourseCode 
INNER JOIN plannedCourses p ON p.CourseCode = s.CourseCode
WHERE COUNT(s.EmployeeNumber) > (SELECT maximum 
                                 FROM plannedCourses 
                                 WHERE s.CourseCode = p.CourseCode);
```

The table layout:

[image: Table layout]

**How can i achieve the desire result?**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your query as follows:

```
select c.coursename
  from courses c
  join subscriptions s
    on (s.coursecode = c.coursecode)
  join PlannedCourses p
    on (p.coursecode = c.coursecode)
  group by c.coursename 
         , p.maximum
  having count(s.Employeenumber) > p.maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has multiple problems.  You are using a correlated subquery, but you are not using the table in its `from` clause.  I think the intention is this:

```
SELECT c.CourseName 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON s.courseCode = c.CourseCode 
group by c.CourseName, c.CourseCode
having COUNT(s.EmployeeNumber) > (SELECT "maximum"
                                  FROM plannedCourses p
                                  WHERE c.CourseCode = p.CourseCode);
```

Comment: I'm getting following error: "Not a GROUP BY expression"... But maybe my entire query is wrong... I'm working with an Oracle database btw.

Comment: Did you change the `where` clause to a `having` clause?

Comment: @LaurentDeWilde . . . In any case, I see what the problem is.  The `s.CourseCode` need an aggregation function.  Instead, I switched to `c.CourseCode` and put it in the `group by`.